# How to show range in equation for multiple variables?

Tags: notation

I'd like to show in the below equation that variables $i$ and $j$ need to be chosen from the range $1$ to $n$, but I am not sure how to properly show this. Can somebody please show me the proper notation for this?

> $y=f(i,j) \qquad i,j = 1,...,n$

Variables $i$ and $j$ are integer and can not be equal to each other. Should I use $\in$ sign instead?

Thank you

Comment: I would just add $i \neq j$ after $i,j = 1, \dots, n$.

Comment: @NESHOM Could you clarify what you are writing? Certainly $y$ can't be $f(i,j)$ for all those pairs $(i,j)$, except this $f$ is constant on that set of indices?

Comment: @Christoph basically I have a long equation that works for any pair of j and j belonging to the range from 0 to n.

Comment: How about $|\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{i,j\}|=n-2$ ;-) It implies everything you have in your situation.

Comment: One thing I would like to clarify is whether $1,2,..,n$ or $1,2,\dots,n$ is more standard. I have heard the latter as the standard, but I suspect this is outdated. See Steven C. Howell's comment to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/543145/120721

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice: Don't force mathematical texts to be formal and contain more symbols than words.

> We have
>   $$f(i,j) = 0$$
>   for all pairs of distinct integers $1\le i,j\le n$.

Comment: thanks, but how about if I have more than one constraint that can't be presented inline with text. This is the reason I'd like to have them in front of the equation.

Comment: Please try make a precise example of what you want to write. Style choices heavily depend on the exact circumstances.

Comment: Basically I have three constraints 1) $i,j=1,...,n$ 2) $i \neq j$ , and 3)$L_j \neq L$. So I don't think it is appropriate to show them all inline.

Comment: I don't think writing "for distinct integers $1\le i,j\le n$ such that $L_j\neq L$" is too bad.

Comment: +1 for "Don't force mathematical texts to ..... contain more symbols than words". Less symbols improve readability a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following notation
$$
y=f(i,j),\;\;\; 1 \leq i,j \leq n
$$

Also, if you want to specify that i and j are integers you can specify it with function domain and codomain:
$$
f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} 
$$

Comment: Thanks, but i and j can't be float numbers like 1.5. They are integer. How can I show this as well?

Comment: @NESHOM: If it is clear from the context that $i,j$ need to be integers, then it's fine. This is the case, for example, if you previously defined $f$ as a function on pairs of integers.

Comment: Well, you can specify that $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $

Answer (score 2):

For example, you could say

> $y = f(i,j)$ for integers $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ with $i \neq j$

or (which is what I would use)

> $y = f(i,j)$ for distinct $i,j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$

Note that if you are not defining $y$ for every viable pair $(i,j)$, you should add *some* after *for*.

---

Since you seem worried that you can put text only in inline formulas, the following is LaTeX code would insert my second example as a *displayed* formula

```
\[
  y = f(i,j) \quad \text{for distinct } i,j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}
\]
```

or you could always write the additional condition right after the formula

```
\[
  y = f(i,j)
\]
for distinct $i,j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$
```

---

**Note:** Even if you could write this only in symbols, you should avoid it, *especially* if you're writing for publication. Professional mathematicians don't write with too many symbols because that would make the text look garbled and hard to understand.

Comment: thanks, these seem to be inline equations, how about a numbered equation (with no text)?

Comment: With LaTeX can add text in displayed equations too: the macro is `\text`. If you really wish to not use it, then you should do like Christoph suggests and write the text either just before or just after the equation. This is the *preferred* form.

Comment: You are right if the equation is as simple as `y=f(i,j)`, but my equation is already more than half page width, and imagine that most of the journals are in two column format, so I am trying the make it as short as possible in width.

Comment: @NESHOM Yet another reason to just write your conditions in the text!

Comment: I prefer the former because I think using belongs to symbol makes it less readable. I agree people read it as `in', but this translation is a small inconvenience in reading.